# How to put superscript and star symbol * on the authors, and set the environment for corresponding author email?

Tags: superscripts, author

I am writing a paper using the IOPScience latex template, which can be obtained through this link:

https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/author-guidelines-for-conference-proceedings/

How can I add superscript on the author and set the corresponding author's email as follows:

[image]

My working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsfonts,longtable,qtree,etoolbox,array,rotating,pgf,tikz,tikz-cd,algorithm,csquotes,algpseudocode,float,listings,color,pdfpages,tabu,blindtext,enumitem,subcaption,makecell,amssymb,hyperref}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{myproof}[2] {\paragraph{Proof}}{\hfill$\square$}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

\begin{document}
\title{Elementray components of electroencephalography signals viewed as prime numbers}

\author{Amirul Aizad Ahmad Fuad, Tahir Ahmad, and Nur Aisyah Mohamad Nor}

\address{Department of Mathematical Sciences, Faculty of Science, Universiti Teknologi Malaysia, 81310 Skudai, Johor, Malaysia}

\ead{aaizad3@graduate.utm.my}

\end{document}
```

that produces:

[image]

How can I solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`jpconf` is the document class used for the Journal of Physics Conference series, and I think it was prepared by IOP. The Journal/publisher should have an up-to-date reference document for the use of the document class.

Google brings up a user's guide, but it is not hosted on the official IOP website and I am not 100% sure how up-to-date it is. But according to what I found, the journal-approved code is surprisingly basic.

[image]